# Validating file upload on use?

Tags: xpages

I want to be able to validate a file upload control BEFORE a file is uploaded.  I want of course a filename to be provided but more important a filename that does not contain any spaces.

If I use conventional validation then the control is validated each time the form is saved.

Is there a way to prevent the user from selecting a file name that I do not want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in my current project.   I use CSJS to check the filename prior to uploading.  In this example, I am using a button that adds the file upload control and several other fields to a new document.  You could change this to check for a specific filename and check for spaces.  My upload control is named "fileUpload3", yours will be what you name it.

```
var x=document.getElementById("#{id:fileUpload3}").value;

if (x==null || x=="" || x.slice(-3) != "pdf")
{
   alert("Store Transfer details in PDF format are required.");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I am confused.   Where does this code go?    Are you saying you have another button that causes the file upload to display?   Do the user needs to press one button, then press the file upload control button?

Comment: Hi Bruce, in my example, I have a button that the user presses to enter a new record, a store transfer in my case.   The file upload control is not hidden and included with other fields the user must enter.  They enter all the field prior to pushing the button.   I put the above code in button's client onclick event.  I have all my SSJS in the Server onClick event.  So, it all has to pass the client side first before the SSJS code will run.  It sounds like you might want something that validates right after the user uploads.  You could try putting the code in the onChange event of the control.

Comment: Also, you probably know this but in order for the attachment to upload, you have to do a full refresh.  A partial refresh will not work.

Comment: FYI: Starting with Domino 9.0.1 you can now upload files using partial refresh